# How to remove numbers in a list and keep reset of the elements? Python

Tags: python, list, strip

```
mylist = ['85639-Joe','653896-Alan','8871203-Zoe','5512-Bob','81021-Jonathan']
```

Above is the list and I want to remove the numbers in the list and keep the names.
I tried the coding below but it didn't work.

```
[s for s in mylist if s.isalpha()]
```

The expected outputs are:

```
['-Joe','-Alan','-Zoe','-Bob','-Jonathan']
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `[x.split('-')[1] for x in mylist]`

Comment: what output do you expect if the list contains `29-Biff42Henderson`? The posted solutions differ in how they would handle the 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use regex to remove digits, as in

```
import re

[re.sub('\d', '', s) for s in mylist]
```

giving

```
['-Joe', '-Alan', '-Zoe', '-Bob', '-Jonathan']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way without using regex:

```
[''.join(y for y in x if not y.isdigit()) for x in mylist]
```

Results:

```
['-Joe', '-Alan', '-Zoe', '-Bob', '-Jonathan']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The built in [`lstrip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) can do this if you pass a string of digits for the optional `chars` parameter.

Regardless of which technique you decide on, please consider making a helper function that does the work. Future maintainers of your code will thank you.

```
mylist = ['85639-Joe','653896-Alan','8871203-Zoe','5512-Bob','81021-Jonathan']
mylist.append('29-Biff42Henderson') # corner case

def strip_numeric_prefix(s: str):
    return s.lstrip('0123456789')

result = [strip_numeric_prefix(s) for s in mylist]
print(result)
```

```
#output
['-Joe', '-Alan', '-Zoe', '-Bob', '-Jonathan', '-Biff42Henderson']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that

```
import re

mylist = ['85639-Joe','653896-Alan','8871203-Zoe','5512-Bob','81021-Jonathan']

print([re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '', word) for word in mylist])
```

Output :

```
['-Joe', '-Alan', '-Zoe', '-Bob', '-Jonathan']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['85639-Joe','653896-Alan','8871203-Zoe','5512-Bob','81021-Jonathan']

temp = ['-'+e.split('-')[1] for e in mylist]
```

result ['-Joe', '-Alan', '-Zoe', '-Bob', '-Jonathan']